# Java SecureRandom internal state

Tags: java, random, shuffle, seeding

I'm trying to shuffle an array of integer as per below,

and from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle,

"An additional problem occurs when the Fisher–Yates shuffle is used with a pseudorandom number generator or PRNG: as the sequence of numbers output by such a generator is entirely determined by its internal state at the start of a sequence, a shuffle driven by such a generator cannot possibly produce more distinct permutations than the generator has distinct possible states. ... "

1. Is it enough if I seed my SecureRandom generator with a lot of bytes ?
2. What's the easiest way to fill the seed byte array ?
   i.e.

   byte[] seed = new byte[2048];
   // fill the seed byte with random stuff, what's the easiest way ?
   SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom(seed);

Code:

```
/**
 * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle
 * 
 * To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
 *      for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
 *          j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
 *          exchange a[j] and a[i]
 */
public int[] shuffle (int[] inSet ) {

    int [] returnSet = Arrays.copyOf(inSet, inSet.length);

    for( int i = inSet.length-1; i > 0; i-- ) {

        // j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
        int j = secureRandom.nextInt(i+1); 

        // swap returnSet[i] and returnSet[j]
        int temp = returnSet[i];
        returnSet[i] = returnSet[j];
        returnSet[j] = temp; 
    }
    return returnSet;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need/want to use a *SecureRandom*? - It is actually meant for use in cryptographic operations.
Btw, I have seen /dev/random and /dev/urandom on Android devices, which may be a good choice for quality-seeding of a PRNG, esp. for cryptography.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good article: "[A Java Programmer’s Guide to Random Numbers](http://blog.uncommons.org/2008/04/03/a-java-programmers-guide-to-random-numbers-part-1-beyond-javautilrandom/)"

Basically, a) You don't want to use `java.util.Random` as it is exhibits periodic behavior (bad randomness), b) `SecureRandom` is a big improvement over `java.util.Random`, but depending on the number of elements you want to shuffle, the degrees of freedom it provides might be too small (see [this section](http://blog.uncommons.org/2008/04/10/a-java-programmers-guide-to-random-numbers-part-3-seeding/) for details). Also another problem is that `SecureRandom` is quite slow. If you have performance problems, you can follow the link above for alternative PRNGs that are faster than `SecureRandom`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the size of the array is not so important as its content.
One common practise is to create the seed on current time.
You can also ask the user (if possible) to apply some random keyboard or mouse input. I've noticed this technique in password managers.

Everything depends on your needs. I bet that quite sensible way would be to take System.currentTimeMillis() (optionally you can play with it by joining it multiple times or hash it).

Comment: The content of the array is irrelevant. The array is being "shuffled", meaning a random permutation is being generated and then applied.